# Integrate $\sqrt{(1-\cos(x))^3}$

Tags: integration

I need help solving the following integration problem:
$$\int \sqrt{(1-\cos(x))^3} dx$$

I know I am supposed to use a trig identity so that I can do a u-sub, but don't know which one or how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $\cos(2x) = 1 - 2 \sin^2(x)$, $1-\cos x = 2 \sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$:

$$\int 2 \sqrt{2} \ \bigg(\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\bigg)^{3/2}  dx$$
$$= 2\sqrt{2} \int \left| \ \sin^3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \right| dx$$

Now from $\sin(3x) = 3 \sin x - 4 \sin^3 x$, $4 \sin^3(x) = 3 \sin(x) - \sin(3x)$, so you can use the identity $\sin^3(x) = \frac{3}{4}\sin(x) - \frac{1}{4}\sin(3x)$.

Comment: Why is the it not $\int sin^\frac{3}{2}\frac{x}{2} dx$?

Comment: Because $2\cdot\frac{3}{2} = 3$.

Comment: Can you explain how you got from $cos(2\theta)$ to $1-cos\theta$?

Comment: @Sam Take the negative sign on both sides: $-\cos(2x) = -1 + 2 \sin^2(x)$. Then add $1$ to both sides; $1 - \cos(2x) = 2 \sin^2(x)$. Then if $x = \frac{u}{2}$, then $1 - \cos(u) = 2 \sin^2(\frac{u}{2})$.

Comment: It should be $\;{\displaystyle\int}\Bigl|\sin^3\bigl(\frac x2\bigr)\Bigr|\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @Bernard Is it still the same integral with the absolute value signs?

Comment: @Sam That is a half-angle identity. $$\cos 2x = 1-2\sin^2 x$$ $$\cos x = 1-2\sin^2 \bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg)$$ $$2\sin^2 \bigg(\frac{x}{2}\bigg) = 1-\cos x$$

Comment: I don't think it's quite the same..

Comment: @Bernard I get your point now – $\sqrt{x}$ can only be positive or zero, but $\sin^3{x/2}$ can be negative. That's why you need to add the absolute value signs.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \sqrt{\left(1-\cos \left(x\right)\right)^3} = 4\sqrt{2}\int \:\frac{y^3}{\left(1+y^2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}dy=2\sqrt{2}\int \:\frac{1}{z^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\frac{1}{z^{\frac{5}{2}}}dz$$
You will get this result by applying these substitutions in sequence
$$y=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\qquad\qquad z= 1+y^2$$
$$\int \sqrt{\left(1-\cos \left(x\right)\right)^3}=\color{red}{4\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{3\sec ^3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}-\frac{1}{\sec \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right)+C}$$